# Creating a feed for a social networking site

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, social-networking

I am making a social networking site and can't decide what the best way to get data from various tables is to display in a feed. Everytime something is stored it has a timestamp stored against it so I was wondering the best way to retrieve data from various different tables ordered by timestamp, and limited to 20 results per page. Ideally I would like mysql to query all of the different tables and order and limit it for me but because the different tables are not all neccessarily related and different data needs to be returned depending on what the table is for I don't think this is going to be possible. I can query each table individually of course but then how do I sort and order all of the information into pages so that all of the different entities are in one ordered list together. The server side language I use is PHP with the codeigniter framework.

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: It is possible to give some structure of your tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you establish a common format for what's returned out of all the separate tables?  So for example, you would write a query that got back FeedTitle, FeedSummary, and Timestamp:

```
 select top 20 *
   from (

 select a.Title as FeedTitle,
        a.A + a.B + a.C as FeedSummary,
        a.Timestamp as TimeStamp
   from a

union all

 select b.Name + ' married ' + b.Spouse as FeedTitle,
        b.AtPlace as FeedSummary,
        b.TimeStamp as TimeStamp
   from b

) as allFeeds
  order by TimeStamp desc
```

Not sure on the exact my-sql syntax, this will work in SQL Server and should be very similar.  It's just pseudocode anyway, the idea is that you'd do some of your application logic in the database in order to hopefully gain a performance boost (so you don't have to sort through lots of data in PHP).

Another approach would be to return the last 20 from each table and let the client side sort through them.  So send them all to the UI and let jQuery code display the top 20, then let the users select the type of feed dynamically, and they'd see the top 20 stories in any one type or any combination of types.

Comment: Two very good ideas there thanks a lot I like the jQuery approach especially, that would add an extra dimension to the feed